# Is there a function to provide formatted display of a deep structure with data?

Tags: abap

I have a deep structure that I would like to display as a tree with the values of each field (sort of like the hierarchical display of a structure you can do in SE11, but with values).

Is there a class or function that does this for you? I really don't want to have to go reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Do you mean logical database (LDB) ex. Tables using NODE SFLIGHT, SCARR etc?

Comment: No, I am not talking about a logical database. I am talking about a deep structure (a structure containing possibly other structures, tables, strings etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say it is faster to do DIY then to search for something generic enough to help you. You can try following coding as basis.

It does the plain recursion through the variable (be it table or structure) and it prints the fields found at bottom...

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  print_structure
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
form print_structure using im_data.

  data: lr_typeref   type ref to cl_abap_typedescr,
        lf_ddic_in   type fieldname,
        lt_dfies     type ddfields,
        lf_string    type c length 200.
      field-symbols: <lt_table> type any table,
                 <ls_table> type any,
                 <lf_field> type any,
                 <ls_dfies> like line of lt_dfies.

  lr_typeref = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( im_data ).
  case lr_typeref->type_kind.
    when cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_table. " internal table
      assign im_data to <lt_table>.
      loop at <lt_table> assigning <ls_table>.
        perform print_structure using <ls_table>.
      endloop.
    when cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct1 or
         cl_abap_typedescr=>typekind_struct2. " deep/flat structure
      lf_ddic_in = lr_typeref->get_relative_name( ).
      call function 'DDIF_FIELDINFO_GET'
        exporting
          tabname     = lf_ddic_in
          all_types   = 'X'
        tables
          dfies_tab = lt_dfies
        exceptions
          not_found = 1
          others    = 0.
      check sy-subrc eq 0.
      loop at lt_dfies assigning <ls_dfies>.
        assign component <ls_dfies>-fieldname of structure im_data to <lf_field>.
        perform print_structure using <lf_field>.
      endloop.
    when others. " any field
      write im_data to lf_string.
      write: / lf_string.
  endcase.

endform.                    "print_structure
```

Comment: Well, it's sort of halfway there because I was hoping for something producing an ALV grid, but I'll take it. Thanks.

Comment: So, just in `when others` replace `write` statement with internal table, which will collect the data (do not forget to channel it as changing parameter through recursion), and finally throw this internal table into ALV grid.

Answer (score 2):

Would an ALV Tree work?  CL_SALV_TREE

Comment: Thanks Bryan, but using CL_SALV_TREE requires a lot of setup, formatting your data, etc. I am looking for a single function that will accept a (deep) structure as input and display the structure with the data as a tree.

Comment: I'm not sure such a thing exists, but it's been a while since I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen such functionality and think there is no one in standard. Can't remeber any situation in standard where such functionality should be used. In my opinion most appropriate way to implement this - to use Column Tree. Take a look into `SAPCOLUMN_TREE_CONTROL_DEMO`